# Include sheet names when exporting Google Spreadsheets to PDF with Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am exporting a Google Spreadsheet to PDF format with Google Apps Script, and would like to 'include sheet names' on the PDF pages. Is this possible to do this from the code?

```
var spreadsheetFile = DocsList.getFileById(spreadsheet_id);
var blob = spreadsheetFile.getAs('application/pdf'); 
blob.setName(spreadsheetFile.getName());
DocsList.getFolder(file_destination).createFile(blob);
```

In the Spreadsheet app it is supported in the UI, so I am wondering whether Apps Scripts supports this too?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `.getAs()` method does not allow for parameters but you can use the spreadsheet api where you can choose all the parameters available from the "normal" Ui.
See this [post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451360/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-google-apps-script-that-includes-only-a-spec/14927409#14927409) to see how to use it, and follow the [github link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4169590)

Here is the demo code as there were a few inconsistencies in the code in ref. (just to illustrate with an example exporting sheet1 with grid and title)

note this will ask for 2 distinct authorizations.

```
function test(){
  var key = "0AnqSFd3iikE3dFd1WEVhMFhYczM5VWpuNDZHQ3AwZEE";
  var pdf = spreadsheetToPDF(key);
  DocsList.createFile(pdf);
}

function spreadsheetToPDF(key) {

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"

  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");  

  var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };

  var name = DocsList.getFileById(key).getName()+".pdf";

  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+key+
                              "&exportFormat=pdf&gid=0&gridlines=true&printtitle=true&size=A4&sheetnames=true&fzr=true&portrait=true&fitw=true", requestData).getBlob().setName(name);

  return pdf;
}

/*
fmcmd=12
size=legal/A4
fzr=true/false
portrait=false/true
fitw=true/false
gid=0/1/2  
gridlines=false/true
printtitle=false/true
sheetnames=false/true
pagenum=UNDEFINED
attachment=false/true  
*/
```

Comment: This information is now outdated, there are no such methods anymore. What are the ways of customizing the pdf when creating it from Sheets now? Appreciate if someone updates.