# Export google spreadsheet to PDF, then save the PDF to drive with a specific name

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a noob in need here I'm afraid, all the code I've found doesn't quite get the job done. Here's what I'm after:

I need a script that, when run, exports the current sheet (not the whole workbook), in portrait and without gridlines, as a PDF, then saves the PDF to a specific file in google drive.

That PDF needs to have a name derived from the values of certain cells in the sheet being exported.

I've stumbled across bits and bobs of code but the only exporter that worked didn't allow for options to be set, and the solutions with a workaround (involving oauth) didn't work at all.

I've tried this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4169590 with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in this post answer works:  [Include sheet names when exporting Google Spreadsheets to PDF with Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168167/include-sheet-names-when-exporting-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-s/21172633#21172633)

It uses oAuth as this is the only possible way to do what you want.

Read carefully the explanations an choose your parameters to suit your needs.