# Export (or print) with a google script new version of google spreadsheets to pdf file, using pdf options

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a google script for exporting (or printing) a new version of google spreadsheet (or sheet) to pdf, with page parameters (portrait/landscape, ...)

I've researched about this and found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168167/include-sheet-names-when-exporting-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-s/21172633#21172633).
There are several similar solutions like this, but only work with old version of google spreadsheet.

Please, consider this code:

```
function exportAsPDF() {
  //This code runs from a NEW version of spreadsheet 

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  var requestData = { "method": "GET", "oAuthServiceName": "google","oAuthUseToken": "always" };

  var ssID1="0AhKhywpH-YlQdDhXZFNCRFROZ3NqWkhBWHhYTVhtQnc"; //ID of an Old version of spreadsheet
  var ssID2="10xZX9Yz95AUAPu92BkBTtO0fhVk9dz5LxUmJQsJ7yPM"; //ID of a NEW version of spreadsheet 

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID1);  //Old version ss object
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID2);  //New version ss object
  var sID1=ss1.getActiveSheet().getSheetId().toString();  // old version sheet id
  var sID2=ss2.getActiveSheet().getSheetId().toString();  // new version sheet id

  //For Old version, this runs ok.
  var url1 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+ssID1+"&gid="+sID1+"&portrait=true"+"&exportFormat=pdf";
  var result1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1 , requestData);
  var contents1=result1.getBlob();
  var pdfFile1=DriveApp.createFile(contents1).setName("FILE1.pdf");

  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+ssID2+"&gid="+sID2+"&portrait=true"+"&exportFormat=pdf";
  var result2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2 , requestData);
  var contents2=result2.getBlob();
  var pdfFile2=DriveApp.createFile(contents2).setName("FILE2.pdf");
}
```

It works right and generates the file “FILE1.pdf”, that can be opened correctly. But for the new version of spreadsheet, it results in error 302 (*truncated server response*) at “*var result2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2 , requestData);*”. Well, it’s ok because the url format for the new version doesn’t include the “key” argument. A correct url for new versions must be like *`"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID2+"/export?gid="+sID2+"&portrait=true&format=pdf"`*

Using this for url2 (*`var url2 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID2+"/export?gid="+sID2+"&portrait=true&format=pdf"`*) it fails again with error  “*Authorization can’t be performed for service: google*”. 
Well, this error could be due to an incorrect scope for the *RequestTokenUrl*. I’ve found the alternative scope `https://docs.google.com/feeds` and set it: `oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://docs.google.com/feed/");` 
After the code runs again, a new error happens at the line with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2 , requestData);`: “*Error OAuth*” … I don’t know how to continue … I’ve tested hundreds of variations without good results.

Any ideas? is correct the scope *docs.google.com/feeds* for new version of spreadsheets? is correct the *oauthConfig*?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my spreadsheet-to-pdf script. It works with the new Google Spreadsheet API.

```
// Convert spreadsheet to PDF file.
function spreadsheetToPDF(id,index,url,name)
{
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //define usefull vars
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  var scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";

  //make OAuth connection
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

  //get request
  var request = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "google",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  //define the params URL to fetch
  var params = '?gid='+index+'&fitw=true&exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&gridlines=false';

  //fetching file url
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/a/"+url+"/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/export"+params, request);
  blob = blob.getBlob().setName(name);

  //return file
  return blob;
}
```

I've had to use the "muteHttpExceptions" parameter to know exactly the new URL. With this parameter, I downloaded my file with the HTML extension to get a "Moved permanently" page with my final url ("https://docs.google.com/a/"+url+"/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/export"+params").

And note that I am in an organization. So I've had to specify its domain name ("url" parameter, ie "mydomain.com").

Comment: Hi crewstyle! Your code works ok! My problem was the correct scope `https://docs.google.com/feeds/`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Worked nicely!  Had to modify it a bit since I'm not in an organization in cahoots with google, but pretty much worked out of the box.  Thanks!!

Comment: Nice solution! Some other params you can use are limiting to a particular sheet with a `gid=` and a selection by specifying a range using row and column indexes e.g. `r1=0&c1=0&r2=55&c2=16`

Comment: @crewstyle. How come when I execute the above code, I get a `Failed to authenticate for service: google` . I authorized anonymous already.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to print a pdf horizontally or that doesn't work for pdfs? &portrait=false is not working. Need horizontal solution.

Comment: Please note that OAuthConfig is no longer supported! https://cloud.google.com/blog/changes-oauth-apps-script

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58728448/1251007 for a working version ...

Answer (score 5):

(Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492812/1677912).)

This function is an adaptation of a script provided by "ianshedd..." [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579#c25).

It:

- Generates PDFs of ALL sheets in a spreadsheet, and stores them in the same folder containing the spreadsheet. (It assumes there's just one folder doing that, although Drive does allow multiple containment.)
- Names pdf files with Spreadsheet & Sheet names.
- Uses the Drive service (DocsList is deprecated.)
- Can use an optional Spreadsheet ID to operate on any sheet. By default, it expects to work on the "active spreadsheet" containing the script.
- Needs only "normal" authorization to operate; no need to activate advanced services or fiddle with `oAuthConfig`.

With a bit of research and effort, you could hook up to an online PDF Merge API, to generate a single PDF file. Barring that, and until Google provides a way to export all sheets in one PDF, you're stuck with separate files.

Script:

```js
/**
 * Export one or all sheets in a spreadsheet as PDF files on user's Google Drive,
 * in same folder that contained original spreadsheet.
 *
 * Adapted from https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579#c25
 *
 * @param {String}  optSSId       (optional) ID of spreadsheet to export.
 *                                If not provided, script assumes it is
 *                                sheet-bound and opens the active spreadsheet.
 * @param {String}  optSheetId    (optional) ID of single sheet to export.
 *                                If not provided, all sheets will export.
 */
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {

  // If a sheet ID was provided, open that sheet, otherwise assume script is
  // sheet-bound, and open the active spreadsheet.
  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get URL of spreadsheet, and remove the trailing 'edit'
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  // Get folder containing spreadsheet, for later export
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  // Get array of all sheets in spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // Loop through all sheets, generating PDF files.
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];

    // If provided a optSheetId, only save it.
    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 

    //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
        + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
        // following parameters are optional...
        + '&size=letter'      // paper size
        + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
        + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
        + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
        + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
        + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);

    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + ' - ' + sheet.getName() + '.pdf');

    //from here you should be able to use and manipulate the blob to send and email or create a file per usual.
    //In this example, I save the pdf to drive
    folder.createFile(blob);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

Variant 2 works with me with options:

```
var requestData = {
  "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
  "oAuthUseToken": "always"
};
```

Then:

```js
var ssID = ss.getId();
var sID = ss.getSheetByName(name).getSheetId();

//creating pdf  
var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/export?gid=" + sID + "&portrait=false&size=A4&format=pdf", requestData).getBlob();

//folder to created pdf in
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);

//creating pdf in this folder with given name
folder.createFile(pdf).setName(name);
```

I can change image size, orientation etc. with listed parameters perfectly.