# OAuth error when exporting Sheet as XLS in Google Apps Script

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script

I had a Google Apps Script to take appointments from my Google Calendar, copy them into a Google Sheet, convert it to XLS and email it. It was working fine until this week.

The initial problem was a 302 error, probably caused by the new version of Sheets. This has been discussed here: [Export (or print) with a google script new version of google spreadsheets to pdf file, using pdf options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-ptrint-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pd)

I got the new location of the file by muting the HTTP exceptions and adjusting the URL accordingly. I also updated the OAuth scope to `https://docs.google.com/feeds/` as suggested.

The program is failing with an "OAuth error" message. When muteHttpExceptions is set to true, the message is "Failed to authenticate to service: google".

I guess this is a scope problem but I really can't see what I've done wrong. Naturally, I've tried a few other possibilities without luck.

I've included the code below. Commented code is the instruction that worked until this week.

```
function getSSAsExcel(ssID)
{
  var format = "xls";

  //var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/";
  var scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=" + scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");

  var requestData = {
    //"muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "google",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };

  //var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ssID
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID 
      + "/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?"
      + "&size=A4" + "&portrait=true" +"&fitw=true" + "&exportFormat=" + format;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);
  var contents = result.getContent();

  return contents; 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's a similar question with an up-to-date answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809987/google-app-scripts-email-a-spreadsheet-as-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using OAuthConfig (which must be auth'ed in the Script Editor) you can pass an OAuth2 token instead, retrievable via `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`.

The code snippet below uses the [Advanced Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to get the export URL, but if you hand construct the URL you'll need to ensure that the Drive scope is still requested by your script (simply include a call to `DriveApp.getRootFolder()` somewhere in your script code).

```
function exportAsExcel(spreadsheetId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(spreadsheetId);
  var url = file.exportLinks[MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  return response.getBlob();
}
```

Comment: The reference for other export types is [link] {https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app}. Instructions for enabling the Drive API are [link] {https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced}.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Koleda, 3 years old, may I ask, how does that get called (or impelemented)? I don't see the function actually exporting. I see it returning a blob.