# Emailing NEW Google Sheets as an Excel file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

Is there anyway to send an Excel .xls version of the NEW Google Sheets to automatically (when triggered by a time frame like for example 'Every Sunday at 9:00pm')?

I have searched many posts in many sites and seen only examples for the old google docs. What I am doing is using **tasker** on my phone to update a time sheet on Google Forms, and I want to make a copy of the sheet, name it using the current date, and then email it to my supervisor on Sunday.

I found this on iGoogle and use it by changing the URL, but Excel keeps saying the file is corrupt.

Here is the [link with the code I was trying to use](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.in/2012/08/send-google-spreadsheet-sheet-to-email.html).

Comment: The new SS  can be converted to xls, see this post answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402693/oauth-error-when-exporting-sheet-as-xls-in-google-apps-script.  The part that sends the email and build the file name from the current date is rather simple and you'll find a lot of code examples ( including the answer below; -)

Comment: Here's a similar question with an up-to-date answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809987/google-app-scripts-email-a-spreadsheet-as-excel

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the example for [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) does a good job explaining but I'll break down the steps for you since I'm not the best coder:

1. To get the file you can use getFileById() or getFilesByName
2. Get the Date for your time zone (See Below)
3. Create an options object ( See Below)
4. Send Email comannd

Code to get time and date from your Spreadsheet:

```
var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var sDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

Example of options Object:

```
var option= {
        from: " YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS",
        name: " YOUR NAME"
        attachments: file.getAs(contentType)
    };
```

For more info about content type see [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String))