# AppScript to split spreadsheet into multiple spreadsheets (based on condition) + automatic email sending of new excel files as attachments

Tags: javascript, automation, spreadsheet, openai-api

I am newbie in terms of AppScript but I have been trying to make something work with chat gpt.
Unfortunately the codes proposed by chatgpt have different flaws and it seems to go in circles going back and forth with some issues.

I have a spreadsheet with data for around 80 suppliers.
In this spreadsheet I have two sheets:

- PO Level: supplier service level per purchasing order
- Item Level: supplier service level at SKU level

Based on original file I need to create a script that will split the original file into one file per supplier that will contain the same data and format as original file, but only for a certain supplier.
Then after creating these files and saving them on GDrive, I need the script to send emails to those suppliers attaching the files as excel, not as a link, based on a different spreadsheet where I have the email addresses.

I have tried multiple codes proposed by chatgpt but either they are attached as pdf or they are attached as link (not the file directly). The issue that appears the most often is related to the script creating pdf's and then not being able to convert them to excel. It has a hard time creating the files directly .xlsx

This is the code below, maybe someone can give me a hint on how I should approach this task, maybe it's not possible to do them all in one script, I don't know to be honest..

Script below (FYI:I have replaced the links to the google drive with XXXX)

```
function splitDataBySupplier() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var poSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("PO Level");
  var itemSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Item Level");
  var dataRangePO = poSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataRangeItem = itemSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataPO = dataRangePO.getValues();
  var dataItem = dataRangeItem.getValues();

  // Load email addresses from separate spreadsheet
  var emailSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXY");
  var emailSheet = emailSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var emailRange = emailSheet.getDataRange();
  var emailData = emailRange.getValues();
  var emailMap = {};
  emailData.forEach(function(row) {
    emailMap[row[0]] = row[1];
  });

  var suppliers = {}; // Object to store data for each supplier

  // Iterate over PO Level data
  for (var i = 1; i < dataPO.length; i++) { // Start from 1 to skip headers
    var supplierName = dataPO[i][2]; // Assuming Supplier name is in the third column
    if (!suppliers[supplierName]) {
      suppliers[supplierName] = { poData: [], itemData: [] };
    }
    suppliers[supplierName].poData.push(dataPO[i]);
  }

  // Iterate over Item Level data
  for (var j = 1; j < dataItem.length; j++) { // Start from 1 to skip headers
    var supplierName = dataItem[j][2]; // Assuming Supplier name is in the third column
    suppliers[supplierName].itemData.push(dataItem[j]);
  }

  // Process data for each supplier
  for (var supplier in suppliers) {
    if (suppliers.hasOwnProperty(supplier)) {
      var supplierData = suppliers[supplier];
      var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(supplier + ".xlsx"); // Create a new spreadsheet in Excel format
      var newPOSheet = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      newPOSheet.setName("Performanta / Comanda");
      var newItemSheet = newSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
      newItemSheet.setName("Performanta / Articol");

      // Write header row for PO Level sheet
      var poHeader = poSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, poSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      newPOSheet.appendRow(poHeader);
      // Write data to PO Level sheet
      newPOSheet.getRange(2, 1, supplierData.poData.length, supplierData.poData[0].length).setValues(supplierData.poData);

      // Write header row for Item Level sheet
      var itemHeader = itemSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, itemSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      newItemSheet.appendRow(itemHeader);
      // Write data to Item Level sheet
      newItemSheet.getRange(2, 1, supplierData.itemData.length, supplierData.itemData[0].length).setValues(supplierData.itemData);

      // Get recipient email from emailMap
      var emailAddress = emailMap[supplier];
      if (emailAddress) {
        // Send email with attachment
        sendEmailWithAttachment(emailAddress, supplier, newSpreadsheet);
      } else {
        Logger.log("Email address not found for supplier: " + supplier);
      }
    }
  }
}

function sendEmailWithAttachment(emailAddress, supplier, spreadsheet) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXX");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());
  var blob = file.getBlob();

  var message = "Performanta lunara a livrarilor " + supplier + "\n\n";
  message += "Buna ziua!\n\n";
  message += "Am atasat fisierul unde puteti vedea performanta livrarilor din luna precedenta.\n";
  message += "Va rugam sa verificati fisierul, iar in maxim 48 de ore sa reveniti catre noi cu un raspuns legat de cum putem imbunatati livrarile, astfel incat performanta livrarilor la nivel de articol sa fie minim 95%.\n\n";
  message += "Multumesc!";

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Performanta lunara a livrarilor " + supplier, message, {
    attachments: [blob]
  });
}
```

I also attached a similar file as example.
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TDFStSarmNvOjf416aGGfSpJUcHIZG_ULv6rHg6ICXw/edit#gid=1933877440](https://stackoverflow.com)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952526/convert-entire-google-sheet-to-xlsx-file) help in any way?