# Convert Google Spreadsheet to Excel XLS with Script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-apps

Let me first say I realize this question has been asked before, so sincere apologies for bringing it up again.  However, I have tried some of the suggestion and can't get it to work out.  I am trying to write a script that will take a Google Spreadsheet, convert it to Excel XLS/XLSX format and then email the converted file as an attachment.  Here's the coding that tries to create the converted file.

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

function test(){
var id = DocsList.getFileById('FILE_ID_HERE');
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls',
googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob()
DocsList.createFile(doc).rename('newfile.xls')
}

function autorise(){
  // function to call to authorize googleOauth
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  var url = 'docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id='+id, googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getContentText();
}
```

I have read that the authorizing procedure is the primary culprit.  I have granted authorization and it appears to run to the line below and then errors.

```
var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls',
googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob()
```

The error message states the following:

```
Request failed for returned code 404. Truncated server response: 
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ><head><meta name="description" content="Web word
processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><link rel="shortcut ic... 
(use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 50, file "Code")
```

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Here's a similar question with an up-to-date answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809987/google-app-scripts-email-a-spreadsheet-as-excel

Answer (score 0):

The code you show (without referencing the source) is for old version of spreadsheets.

It does not work for new version.

Read the [documentation on drive advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), you will find all the explanation to do what you want.

this post should help : [OAuth error when exporting Sheet as XLS in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402693/oauth-error-when-exporting-sheet-as-xls-in-google-apps-script)