# Exporting google spreadsheet as xlsx using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

It seems that with new version of Google spreadsheet it is no longer possible to download entire Google Spreadsheet using JS. So far I have been using this method (which still works fine for files which were created earlier):

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=' + id + '&exportFormat=xlsx');

 xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);

 xhr.onload = function() {
      ...
 };

 xhr.send();
```

[I have found the new download url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-ptrint-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pd):

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/_ID_/export?format=xlsx&id=_ID_
```

But unfortunately there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header so the link cannot be accessed using JS. Is there any other possibility I can download the file?

Google Drive API displays export url as:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=_ID_&exportFormat=xlsx
```

But there is also no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Is there any other possibility to download this file using only JS?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download it using this url:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=XXX&output=xls
```

I've created an example that works here:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        console.log('success', this.responseText.length);
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AsnymCBa0S5PdEtZdnEzcjlTenBIcldRNFMtSUdNUkE&output=xls', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/b47wno47/

Comment: This will work only for public spreadsheets. I'm considering private as code in my question states.

Comment: For private spreadsheets you need to use the Google Drive API to Auth before retrieving a spreadsheet

Comment: Oh don't tell... where do you think gapi.auth.getToken().access_token came from?

Comment: What value would I use for "key"?  Is this identical to "_ID_" in the original question?

Comment: @jochen yes you use the Spreadsheet ID as the key, and the spreadsheet needs to be set as public