# Is it possible to create a single pdf from multiple Google spreadsheets?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, blob

I am able to create a pdf from a single Google spreadsheet sheet [using this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-ptrint-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pd).

Is it possible to tweak this code to allow multiple sheets from different spreadsheets to be merged into a single pdf?  Or would I need to take an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't but you can easily merge spreadsheets into a temporary spreadsheet and export this one as pdf.

to merge sheets from different origins you have a choice of methods to choose from, below is a small example that gets 1 sheet from the active SS and one from another SS and merge it in a "temp" SS.

The destination spreadsheet will have 3 sheets :

- sheet1
- copy of sheet1
- copy of sheet1 1

You'll just have to clean it up and rename to your needs.

code :

```
function mergeSS(){
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.create('temp');
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];// one opening method
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NmeLtT4_9jRzau__________o23KG8hYdJj6w').getSheets()[0];// another opening method
  s1.copyTo(dest);
  s2.copyTo(dest);
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks.  I thought of this approach as well.  My issue is I have over 100 different sheets to aggregate.  I'm worried that I'll hit some sort of rate max or the temp spreadsheet won't like having so many sheets added.

Comment: Not sure it would fail... eventually add a small pause between SS creation using utilities.sleep(). I recently used a script that creates 20+ SS without issue (I know it's less than 100 but it was already not that bad ;-)- btw, thx for accepting.