# UrlFetch from Google Sheet exportLink['application/pdf'] not returning PDF data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I create and send a periodic email as an update from a Google Sheet. For various client reasons this is done 3 ways, as a link to the Sheet, and as attachments (`PDF` and `XLSX`).

This was working 'til recently. The XSLX attachment still works, but the PDF is no longer sent as a response to a `UrlFetch` to the `file.exportLinks('application/pdf')` url. No matter what the request headers it always returns as `Content-Type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`

Did something else undocumented change that I am missing here?

```
function exportAsPDF(spreadsheetId) {
  spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId || 'SECRET_ID';

  var file = Drive.Files.get(spreadsheetId),
      url = file.exportLinks['application/pdf'];

  url += '&format=pdf&size=7&fzr=true&portrait=true&fitw=true&gid=0&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=true'

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
          }
      });

  var headers = response.getAllHeaders(); // revealing content-type returned isn't pdf
  var pdfBlob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');      
  var pdfString = pdfBlob.getDataAsString(); // this naturally throws an error

  return response.getBlob(); // this returns to the send mail script
}
```

Comment: `Drive` is what I have mapped Google Advanced Drive API to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to get PDFs using the utility from [Convert all sheets to PDF with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367547/convert-all-sheets-to-pdf-with-google-script/30492812#30492812).

That working script modifies the spreadsheet's edit URL into an export URL, which looks like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<%SS-ID%>/export?exportFormat=pdf...
```

The advanced Drive service gives an export URL formatted like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=<%SS-ID%>&exportFormat=pdf...
```

I'd expect the URL provided by `exportLinks` to be more reliable than the hack in the working script. Apparently, it's not.

This has been raised as [Issue 5114](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5114). Star it to receive updates.

Comment: that is working - funny, i used to use that URL before sheets converted to New Sheets stopped it working :/