# How can I open the print window (export to pdf) via Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

I have a script that created a menu in a spreadsheet. When I click on the menu option, it asks for what line I want to print and it sets the data in another sheet (formatted for printing). I want to be able to open the print window of one of my sheets. Is there any way to achieve this?

I don't want to export the pdf automatically because I want to be able to choose the printer and the page format.

Thank you

Comment: How about JavaScripts window.print();

Comment: How can I use this in Google App Scripts?

Comment: From a dialog or sidebar or a web app. Anything that has pure JavaScript available in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is currently not possible in Google Apps Script. There is no option to automate opening the print dialog.

As a workaround, you could programmatically [export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367547/convert-all-sheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-script) the Sheet you want to print as a PDF and use Apps Script's [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) to mail it to your printer.

If you are still interested in this feature and would like to communicate it to the Google Sheets team, I suggest you create a Feature Request in the Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).