# Is there a query parameter to set margin on Google Sheet export to pdf using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I searched for an answer but haven't found one. A similar one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367547/convert-all-sheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-script) as well but it doesn't list a parameter to set margin. Setting margin is available when a Sheet is downloaded as pdf from the GUI file menu

Comment: For example, is this information useful for your situation? https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/c37d45619d5661cab078be2a3f2fd2bb

Comment: Beautiful. I would mark it as correct answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that Andrew Roberts's this gist is useful. Also I think that when it is post as an answer, it will be also useful for other users.

Comment: Kindly post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here it is - setting the margins of a PDF!

https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/c37d45619d5661cab078be2a3f2fd2bb

Big thanks for Tanaike for the acknowledgement :)

[Spencer Easton also has to get a mention as the "shoulders" I was standing on!](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70)

Here ends the lovefest.