# Error while merging 2 specific Google sheets tabs into one pdf using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf

I am trying to merge 2 specific sheets (both have different Data ranges, **Sheet1->A2:Q28** , **Sheet2->A1:I27**) into one pdf. For that, I found this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367547/convert-all-sheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-script) that explains about merging of sheets. Specifically, converting all sheets into one pdf (sheets can not be hidden). Here is the code:

```
function convertSpreadsheetToPdf(spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName) {

  var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId ? spreadsheetId : spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetName ? spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId() : null;  
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1t6ns346GNX_gP-uGkwE43egGhTCaWgKO');
  var pdfName = pdfName ? pdfName : spreadsheet.getName();
  
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if optSheetId is provided
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  folder.createFile(blob);
  
  folder.createFile(blob);

}
```

If I run this function for one sheet like this:

```
function test(){
  var pdfName = "123"
  convertSpreadsheetToPdf("","Sheet1",pdfName);
}
```

Here is a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OEcoL9RKlWT2LiFKJsY8OixbDdgXBo3AmoA3DcjSuY/edit#gid=1182735361) for which I want to run this function. It shows the following **error**:

> Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code
> 500. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use
> muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I want to modify it to merge only 2 sheets into one pdf. Let's assume the names of the sheets are `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet with dummy values so that we can further experiment or try different approaches based on the sample sheet that you could provide?

Comment: thank you for your response, here is the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OEcoL9RKlWT2LiFKJsY8OixbDdgXBo3AmoA3DcjSuY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: About `Error while merging 2 specific Google sheets tabs into one pdf using Google Apps Script`, can you provide detailed information about the error?

Comment: thank you for your reply, first of all I am not able to use both (sheet1 and sheet2) in the function to create a single pdf, if I run this function only for one sheet to create a pdf , I receive somthing like this: `Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 500. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`

Comment: I have updated my question for further clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that Unicode characters like  (Unicode Version:10.0),  (Unicode Version:6.0), and  (Unicode Version:6.0) are included in the Spreadsheet. In my experience, I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. In the current stage, unfortunately, when such Unicode characters are included, it seems that an error occurs. Also, I could replicate the same error with you.

In order to avoid this error, it is required to remove or replace such Unicode characters. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `test()` is modified.

```js
function test(){
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const replacement = [
    {"from": "", "to": "#1"},
    {"from": "", "to": "#2"},
    {"from": "", "to": "#3"},
  ];
  replacement.forEach(o => s.createTextFinder(o.from).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(o.to));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var pdfName = "123"
  convertSpreadsheetToPdf("","",pdfName);

  replacement.forEach(o => s.createTextFinder(o.to).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(o.from));
}
```

- In this modification, the Unicode characters are replaced. If you want to remove this, please modify the value of `to` to `""`.
- When I tested this modified script to your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that a PDF file including "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" was created.

#### Note:

Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. But, if your actual Spreadsheet has more sheets including "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", and "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are more large sheet, and you want to export the specific ranges from them, how about the following sample script? In this case, the ranges of `Sheet1!A2:Q28` and `Sheet2!A1:I27` are exported as a PDF file.

##### 1. Install Javascript library.

In this sample script, in order to merge PDF data, a Javascript library of `pdf-lib.min.js` is used. So, please copy and paste the script from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js to the script editor of your Google Apps Script and save the script.

The sample script for merging PDF data is from https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/10/merging-multiple-pdf-files-as-a-single-pdf-file-using-google-apps-script/ (Author: me).

##### 2. Sample script

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save the script.

```js
async function myFunction() {
  // This is from your question.
  const output = [
    {sheetName: "Sheet1", range: "A2:Q28"},
    {sheetName: "Sheet2", range: "A1:I27"},
  ];
  const conv = [
    {"from": "", "to": "#1"},
    {"from": "", "to": "#2"},
    {"from": "", "to": "#3"},
  ];

  // Retrieve PDF data.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  conv.forEach(o => ss.createTextFinder(o.from).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(o.to));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  const headers = {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
  const data = output.map(({sheetName, range}) => {
    const s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const gid = s.getSheetId();
    const r = s.getRange(range);
    const r1 = r.getRow() - 1;
    const c1 = r.getColumn() - 1;
    const r2 = r1 + r.getNumRows();
    const c2 = c1 + r.getNumColumns();
    const url = `${url_base}export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf`
      + '&size=letter'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=false'
      + `&gid=${gid}&r1=${r1}&c1=${c1}&r2=${r2}&c2=${c2}`;
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers, muteHttpExceptions: true});
    if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) {
      console.log(res.getContentText())
    }
    return new Uint8Array(res.getContent());
  });
  conv.forEach(o => ss.createTextFinder(o.to).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(o.from));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const setTimeout = function(f, t) {
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  }
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(pdfData.getPageCount())].map((_, i) => i));
    pages.forEach(page => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample1.pdf"));
}
```

- When this script is run, the ranges of `Sheet1!A2:Q28` and `Sheet2!A1:I27` are exported as a PDF file.
- If your Spreadsheet includes the values of `#1, #2, #3`, please modify `conv`.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: thank you for your solution, so is it not possible to add unicode characters (,,)?

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `so is it not possible to add Unicode characters (,,)?`, in the current stage, when those characters are included, it seems that it cannot be exported as PDF data. I apologize for this. In this case, how about reporting this to Google issue tracker? By the way, when you tested my script, what result did you obtain?

Comment: @Roomi About `it worked, thank you for your answer`, thank you for testing it. As additional information, for example, even when  (Unicode Version:6.1) is included, the error occurs. But, when ❤ (Unicode Version:1.1) is included, no error occurs. It seems that it might depend on the version of Unicode.

Comment: one last question, in your answer line 10, you used `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

I tried `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` but it throws an error `setTimout is not defined`. Any suggestion to resolve this issue?