# "ReferenceError: setTimeout" while merging two tabs into one pdf using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, error-handling

Continuing my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309540/error-while-merging-2-specific-google-sheets-tabs-into-one-pdf-using-google-apps/76311467?noredirect=1#comment134569001_76311467), I want to merge two tabs of Google Sheets into one pdf. [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) proposed a solution that worked on this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OEcoL9RKlWT2LiFKJsY8OixbDdgXBo3AmoA3DcjSuY/edit#gid=1182735361) as required. Here is the proposed code with [javascript library](https://%20https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js):

```
function myFunction(e) {

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();

   const output = [
    {sheetName: "Quan", range: "A2:Q28"},
    {sheetName: "Qual", range: "A1:I27"},
    ];

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
    const headers = {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
    const data = output.map(({sheetName, range}) => {
    const s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const gid = s.getSheetId();
    const r = s.getRange(range);
    const r1 = r.getRow() - 1;
    const c1 = r.getColumn() - 1;
    const r2 = r1 + r.getNumRows();
    const c2 = c1 + r.getNumColumns();
    const url = `${url_base}export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf`
      + '&size=letter'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=false'
      + `&gid=${gid}&r1=${r1}&c1=${c1}&r2=${r2}&c2=${c2}`;
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers, muteHttpExceptions: true});
   
    if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) {
      console.log(res.getContentText())
      }
    return new Uint8Array(res.getContent());
     });
 
     const setTimeout = function(f, t) {
     Utilities.sleep(t);
     return f(); }
     const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
 
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(pdfData.getPageCount())].map((_, i) => i));
    pages.forEach(page => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
    }
    const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1t6ns346GNX_gP-uGkwE43egGhTCaWgKO');
    var pdf = folder.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample1.pdf"));

    console.log(pdf.getUrl())
    sheet.getRange("AW7").setValue(pdf.getUrl());

}
```

The issue is this script works only for this [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OEcoL9RKlWT2LiFKJsY8OixbDdgXBo3AmoA3DcjSuY/edit#gid=1182735361). If I copy it or access the other [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rNlXGlno8DPnqd4IGs2eyRrX0CHsDUR4ylc9qBwDQ_k/edit?usp=sharing) with url then it shows the following error message:

> ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined (anonymous) @ JS
> Library.gs:15 X   @ JS Library.gs:15 (anonymous)  @ JS Library.gs:15
> (anonymous)   @ JS Library.gs:15 (anonymous)  @ JS Library.gs:15 a    @ JS
> Library.gs:15

In line 6 of the code, the statement is `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, I want to use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether this is a direct solution of your current issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function myFunction(e) {
```

#### To:

```
const setTimeout = function (f, t) {
  Utilities.sleep(t);
  return f();
}

async function myFunction(e) {
```

- Please add `async`.
- In this modification, `setTimeout` is moved as the global.

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I apologize that I couldn't notice that issue.