# Set Timeout error while merging multiple pdfs into one using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf, google-drive-api

I have a script that is supposedly used for merging multiple pdf files into one using Google Apps Script, here is the code snippet:

```
async function newMain() {
  // Retrieve PDF data.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // Please set your sheet name.
  const ids = sheet.getRange("D1:D2").getDisplayValues().filter(([d]) => d);
 
  const data = ids.map(([id]) => new Uint8Array(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes()));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < pdfData.getPageCount(); j++) {
      const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [j]);
      pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    }
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
}
```

But when I run it, I receive the following error:

> ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined
> eval
> X
> eval
> eval
> eval
> a

Any guidance to resolve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
async function newMain() {
  // Retrieve PDF data.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // Please set your sheet name.
  const ids = sheet.getRange("D1:D2").getDisplayValues().filter(([d]) => d);

  const data = ids.map(([id]) => new Uint8Array(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes()));

  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < pdfData.getPageCount(); j++) {
      const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [j]);
      pdfDoc.addPage(page);
    }
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create a PDF file.
  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample2.pdf"));
}
```

- In this modification, `setTimeout` is modified to `Utilities.sleep`.

Comment: @EagleEye As another approach, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76314171) or [this repository](https://github.com/tanaikech/PDFApp) might be also useful.