# Building link to export sheet as PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, blob

I've been trying to export specific sheets as PDFs for mailing purposes, and found that I needed them to be in a specific format. I went around looking for code to use and ended up finding this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761058#comment24

Although I have incorporated quite a bit of my own code, a good chunk of it is the same as in the link I posted above, and it works quite well except for one thing.

As seen in the code below, I've chosen to have fit width as "false" since some of my sheets have a lot of columns. However, the PDFs I get are always in the fit to width format, and not actual size, making it practically impossible to read should it be printed. I've tried to look into it, but my attempts so far have turned up empty-handed, so I've finally decided to try and ask here.

```
     var url = ss.getUrl(); 


  //remove the trailing 'edit' from the url 
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,''); 

  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf 
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf 
  //below parameters are optional... 
  '&size=A4' + //paper size 
  '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape 
  '&fitw=false' + //fit to width, false for actual size 
  '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=true&pagenumbers=true' + //hide optional headers and footers 
  '&gridlines=true' + //hide gridlines 
  '&fzr=false' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page 
  '&gid=' + spaceman.getSheetId();

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
    Logger.log("URL: " + url + url_ext);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, { 
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token 
      } 
    });
```

Any help or suggestions on how to solve this issue of mine would be greatly appreciated. Of course, if something needs to be clarified or added to the original post then I would be happy to do so.

**EDIT:** I've been really stuck on this so I haven't really done anything else to the script, just tested the script again today and suddenly I'm getting actual size instead of fitw, so I suppose it could've been a bug?

Comment: Try to add '&source=labnol'. don't know if it will work, but may worth the shot. [Source](https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Pierre-MarieRichard , though sadly there doesn't seem to be any noticeable difference between having it and not.

Comment: I found some parameters on some old code I wrote, but I don't have a clue of what they do. If you want to try : 0=mp&1=f&2=print&3=1&format=pdf

Comment: labnol? what is that? its a domain name?

Comment: @OblongMedulla it seems to be a domain related to the author of Pierre-Marrie's source

Comment: You may want to try this [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284142/6092067) from a related SO post. Use  `muteHttpExceptions` parameter with value set to `true`. See this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) for more information. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Teyam Tried to set muteHttpExceptions as true, though I'm not sure I did it properly. If I did do it properly then it didn't work. I updated the code in the post to include the muteHttpExceptions part.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a bug- But if you access the URL direct, you can replicate your issue-

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ADDYOURIDSSHERE/export?fitw=false&format=pdf
```

Comment: Not getting actual size with this either, on any of the sheets that is