# Create PDF from Google Doc and get its link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have created a PDF file from Google Doc as

```
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(myGoogleDoc).getAs("application/pdf")
```

Now I want to get the link of this PDF file, so anyone can click on that link and download the file.

Comment: from what I know you need to create a file in the drive then grab the url you can also go check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457298/building-link-to-export-sheet-as-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getUrl()` method to get get the url of the file to open it with Google App like Drive PDF Viewer ,Google Docs ,etc.

Drive PDF Viewer will be used to open your converted PDF in Google Drive.

Refer To:[Search for getUrl() on this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/)

You can even get the url of a folder to open it in drive or other Google App.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't.

I already have a pdf and I don't see option to use getURL() there.

Comment: Search in the documentation for the method.

Comment: My apologies, but if you try my code and you will see that getUrl() parameter isnt available there.