# Downloading Google Sheet as PDF in landscape mode with Google Sheet REST API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

We use the Google Drive REST API to export Google Sheets as PDF.
We are NOT using Google Script.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

It works, but is there a way of specifying extra options, such as the paper orientation?

It is possible when using the Google Sheets app with the File > Download as menu.

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-print-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf

Comment: No. This is not using the REST API. I did try adding a portrait=false query parameter with the REST API, but this had no effect.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't understand the situation about ``I did try adding a portrait=false query parameter with the REST API, but this had no effect.``. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can you show us the detail information that you tried? If you can do, please update your question.

Comment: If you issue GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media&portrait=false the portrait parameter has no effect

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

Comment: @DaImTo this is not a duplicate. As mentioned in the title this is about the REST API, not Google Script

Comment: @DalmTo honestly this is not a duplicate can you fix this?