# How to programmatically print and download a PDF of a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, download, google-sheets

**Solved**

In New Sheets, I wanted to create a script, assigned to a button, that bypasses having to use the print dialog by specifying print options, including the active range, exporting and downloading a PDF of the sheet, not saving the file to Google Drive.

I consulted code by [crewstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997924/export-or-ptrint-with-a-google-script-new-version-of-google-spreadsheets-to-pd), [Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168167/include-sheet-names-when-exporting-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-s/21172633#21172633), [Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402693/oauth-error-when-exporting-sheet-as-xls-in-google-apps-script), and others, but because of [a Google bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478), .fetch currently fails to authenticate for the spreadsheets service when muteHttpExceptions is true. But [this workaround](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579#c25) bypasses authentication altogether and answers my question.

The result is mimicking the native print behavior except for temporarily opening a new tab at download, which is minor, but I would still like even to fix that if possible. I would also be nice to programmatically rename the downloaded file but this isn't vital.

```
function printPdf() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  var pdfOpts = '&size=0&fzr=false&portrait=false&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=true&gid='+gid;
  var row2 = sheet.getMaxRows() - 3;
  var printRange = '&c1=1' + '&r1=1' + '&c2=42' + '&r2='+row2; // B2:APn
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(200).setHeight(50);
  app.setTitle('Print this sheet');

  var link = app.createAnchor('Download PDF', url).setTarget('_self');
  app.add(link);

  ss.show(app);
}
```

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168167/include-sheet-names-when-exporting-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-s/21172633#21172633

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: This is apparently [a known defect](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478) that Google is working on. @Sergeinsas

Comment: @thornomad, what was your solution?

Comment: Can you please provide an answer if there is one, or otherwise remove the "Solved" from the top?