# print html backgroud color in pdf with google apps script blob.getAs()

Tags: google-apps-script

1. I'm  generating an html file using HTMLService

   1. Then I create a file out of the htmlOutput with the DriveService
   2. Last I generate a pdf file with the blob.GetAs("application/pdf")

This works all fine, but the background colors don't get printed. Is there a way to bring the background color html styles in the pdf ?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue!
Add this to a style-tag in you html file.

```
@media print {body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}}
```

For me that resolved the issue.
(found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview/15253634))

Comment: This just made my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different data flow to get your pdf as described in [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168167/include-sheet-names-when-exporting-google-spreadsheets-to-pdf-with-google-apps-s/21172633#21172633) and in [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451360/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-google-apps-script-that-includes-only-a-spec/14927409#14927409).

I didn't test with colored backgrounds but it is worth giving it a try.